# Problem with Pixel Perfect Camera and Cinemachine in Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, components, pixel

I have a problem when I add a 2D pixel-perfect camera component onto the camera and a Cinemachine 2D virtual camera in the scene, the camera jitters around.

This is my configuration for the virtual camera

[image: Virtual Camera]

This is my configuration for the pixel-perfect camera component

[image: pixel-perfect camera component]

I used the experimental 2D renderer in the universal render pipeline.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Recently figured out what was cousing it. So it's universal render pipeline with it's pixel perfect camera (experimental) component. I turned off urp and switched to pixel perfect camera (not experimental) and everything is smooth now, but sadly no more urp. So let's just hope they will fix it in the future and there will be oportunity to use urp with pixel perfect without jittering.
P.S. if you'll find another solution please let me know)

Comment: Has anyone find a solution to using URP, Cinemachine's 2D Camera, and Pixel Perfect Camera? I'm getting the camera jitter/swings too!

Answer (score 0):

I just found this: [Cinemachine Pixel Perfect extension](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@7.1/manual/pixel-cinemachine.html).

Which doesn't fix it for me because I'm using a Target, but in case anyone has this problem and wants to try it.

The documentation even says:

> The following are the current limitations of the extension:
>
> When a virtual camera with the Pixel Perfect extension is set to follow a Target Group, there may be visible choppiness when the virtual camera is positioned with the Framing Transposer component.